overleaf error code to be rectified
Can you please help in rectifying this error code in the overleaf?
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

                                              
l.1005 \ProcessOptionsKV[p]{Gm}
                               %
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count199
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.


Welcome to TeX.SE.  Can you format the error message the same way it appears in the log?  Can you post the minimal amount of code necessary to cause this error message?

The error message is from latex and so not related to overleaf, you would get the same error wherever you run tex, but you have not shown the error only the following help text and you have not shown your input. show the error message from the lines above that starts with !

You have not shown your input or the main text of the error message, only the final lines of the message with some help text.
However you have a bad option to the geometry package. The full message will show which option is incorrect, for example this document
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[wibble]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Produces the error
! Package keyval Error: wibble undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1005 \ProcessOptionsKV[p]{Gm}
                               %
? 

which shows that wibble is not a valid option, and then shows some further context as shown in your question.
